# Enviar correo en C# (WPF) desde Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, email

He probado varios códigos de ejemplo que encontré por aquí y en la ayuda de Microsoft pero ninguno me funciona y es bastante urgente, alguien sabe cómo podría hacer?

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: y el codigo de lo que llevas?

Answer (score 1):

En este código tienes para insertar imagen en el html(no como archivo adjunto) y como adjuntar un archivo. Si no te interesa esto ultimo quita esa linea y ve jugando con ello.
instálate en el  administrador de NuGet : MimeKit y MailKit

```
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Net.Imap;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Search;
using MailKit.Security;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Utils;
```

```
  public static void EnviarCorreo()
        {
            string correoEmisor = "correo@correo.com";
            string passEmisor = "xxxxxxx";
            string correoReceptor = "correo@correo.com";
            MimeMessage mensaje = new MimeMessage();
            //DATOS EMISOR - MailboxAddress( nombre del emisor, email del emisor)
            mensaje.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("El nombre emisor", correoEmisor));
            //PARA  -  MailboxAddress( Nombre del receptor, email del receptor)
            mensaje.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("El nombre receptor", correoReceptor));
            //ASUNTO
            mensaje.Subject = "Asunto de mensajeria";

            BodyBuilder cuerpoMensaje = new BodyBuilder();
            cuerpoMensaje.TextBody = "hola";
            //cuerpoMensaje.HtmlBody = "Hola <b>soy Ainoha</b> ";
            //meter imagen en texto
            // Para hacer referencia a selfie.jpg desde el texto html, necesitaremos agregarlo 
            // a builder.LinkedResources y luego usar su valor de ID de contenido en el img src. 
            var imagen = cuerpoMensaje.LinkedResources.Add(@"C:\Users\Desktop\image.png");
            imagen.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();

            cuerpoMensaje.HtmlBody = string.Format("Hola <b>Soy Ainohal</b> esto es una prueba <br/>Otra linea.<br/><br/>" + @"<img src="" cid:{0}"" />", imagen.ContentId);

            //Adjuntos
            cuerpoMensaje.Attachments.Add(@"C:\PROG_LOCAL\escritorio\archivo.xlsx");

            //configurar el cuerpo del mensaje
            mensaje.Body = cuerpoMensaje.ToMessageBody();
            //Conexion y envio
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger("smtp.log"));
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
            client.Connect("smtp.xxxxxx.es", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            client.Authenticate(correoEmisor, passEmisor);
            client.Send(mensaje);
            client.Disconnect(true);

        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel!